# Update Array from Document (MongoDB) in Javascript not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've looking for an answer for like 5 five hours straight, hope somebody can help. I have a MongoDb collection **results** (I'm using mLab) which looks like this:

```
    {
    "user":"5818be9c74aaec1824c28626"
    "results":[{
             "game_id":14578,
             "level1":-1,
             "level2":-1,
             "level3":-1
         }, 
     { ....
     }],
         { "user":....
         }
     }
```

"user" is a MongoID I save in a previous part of the code, "results" is a record of scores. When an user does a new score, I have to update the score of the corresponding level (I'm using NodeJS).
This is one of the things I've tried so far.

```
 app.get('/levelCompleted/:id/:time', function (request, response) {
 var id = request.params.id;
 var time = parseInt(request.params.time);
 var u= game.getUserById(id);
 var k = "results.$.level"+(u.level);
 //I build the key to update dinamycally
 dbM.collection("results").update(
    {user:id,
    "results.game_id":u.game_id
    //u has its own game_id
    },
    {$set: {k:time}}
);
...
response.send(...);
```

});

I've checked the content of every variable and parameter, tried also using $elemMatch and dot notation, set upsert and multi, with no results. I've used an identical command on mongo shell and it has work on the first try.

[Update with Mongo Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwBud.png)

If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong or point me in the right direction, it would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using Mongoose or just Mongo driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a MongoId as a field in a MongoDB, you can't just pass a string with the id to do the query, you have to identify that string as an `ObjectId` (Id type in Mongo). Just add a new `require` in your node.js file.

```
var ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
```

And use the imported constructor in your update request.

```
dbM.collection("results").update(
    {user:ObjectID(id),...
    ...
    }
```